# How to show an image on the browser from binary data

Tags: javascript, html, rest, imageurl

I created a restful service which returns a image file as FileInputStream instance in http response. In the javascript side, when it receives this data, how can I render it on a `<img>` tag? I know img tag accepts an url but I am not sure whether it can read raw data stream? If not, how to solve this issue.

Below is the code in server side. It will return a FileInputStream instance to the client side. I want to know how I can write javascript to read this inputstream and render it on `<img>` html tag.

```
@Path("/file/{courseId}/{filename}")
@GET
public Response getCourseVideoById(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                              @PathParam("courseId") String courseId,
                                   @PathParam("filename") String fileName) {
    FileInputStream file = courseService.getCourseFile(courseId, fileName);
    return Response.ok(file).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = "+fileName).build();
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried to write? Please show us

Comment: Are you sure that's a static image and not a video stream?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code in server side. It will return a FileInputStream instance to the client side. I want to know how I can write javascript to read this inputstream and render it on  html tag.

```
@Path("/file/{courseId}/{filename}")
@GET
public Response getCourseVideoById(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                              @PathParam("courseId") String courseId,
                                   @PathParam("filename") String fileName) {
    FileInputStream file = courseService.getCourseFile(courseId, fileName);
    return Response.ok(file).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = "+fileName).build();
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer; it should have been an edit to the question. I did that now.